# Getting windows domain name

Tags: http, asp-classic

I need to get the Windows domain name from Internet Explorer using classic asp (I could try it in another way if with classic asp it's not possible).

I need to do this in order to insert the domain name into a database row.

So again, in summary, I need to retrieve the Windows computer domain name from the Internet Explorer that is accessing to a particular webpage.

Any idea where I could find and example in order to do that?, is it possible?

Comment: are you using Windows Authentication? Which version of IIS? Does the web server's domain and the user's domain have a relationship (same domain, same forest, etc.).

Comment: I don't really know what authentication system they use there, but I suppose they authenticate against different domains and that's why they want to store that information. The client wants to insert the domain windows name along with other information into a table. They use Internet Explorer 8, and I have to use asp for legacy reasons (they have an IIS server with .asp support but not php support for example). I understand seeing your response that it's not as simple as to get the information from some kind of http header (for example the user agent). I will inquire about that data tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers by default use the web protocols (think Http, Html, Ssl, etc.). By your username I know that you are familiar with the RFCs that define these protocols.

Windows networks use a different protocols. The Domain is a logical security boundary in Windows networks. Yes, in modern versions of Windows Domain security uses standard protocols like Kerberos.

The problem you'll have is that a web browser doesn't normally send extra information to a web server about the client. That would be a huge security problem. So, by default a web browser (even IE) would not volunteer any network security information in an Http request.

When your web server requires client authentication, the web browser then must provide more security information to the server. Depending on the type of authentication your web server requires, your browser will send different information. For instance, in Http Basic authentication, the browser will send a username and password.

To my knowledge, the best way to get Windows Network Domain information from a web browser is to force the browser to authenticate using Windows Authentication. This is a special authentication mode that Microsoft built that pushes Microsoft network security information over the standard Http protocol. However, in order for this to work:

1. Users must be running IE on Windows
2. Web server must be IIS on Windows
3. The client and server must have a Windows security relationship
4. IIS must be enabled for Windows Auth
5. There are many restrictions about the network path between the client and the server. Proxies and firewalls will typically prevent the IE Client from using windows authentication with IIS.

If you can live with this checklist, I think you will find the domain info in the one of the http headers. You may have to parse it out of the username which will be domain\user. But I'm sorry I don't remember the specifics. This should work even in classic ASP. More info on Windows Authentication is available at http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301387.aspx is about ASP.NET, but it says:

> For a user authenticated using Windows
>   authentication, the name is of the
>   form domainname\username, where
>   domainname is the name of the domain
>   in which the user is registered (or
>   machine name if it's a local account
>   instead of a domain account), and
>   username is the user's name.

In Classic ASP, try Request.ServerVariables ("AUTH_USER") or Request.ServerVariables ("LOGON_USER")

One alternative to Windows Authentication is to use Basic Auth and force the user to login with their windows credentials as domain\user. This however presents other security issues and you should do this only over SSL. However, this technique will work over the Internet and doesn't require a security relationship between the client PC and the server. This would also work for non-IE browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have more than enough info now to start working around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone happens to get the same problem, here is the solution I've implemented (pretty much what Michael Levy said).

You have to activate Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication.

You can read here how to do it: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5f8fe119-4095-4094-bba5-7dec361c7afe.mspx?mfr=true

After that you can use:

> In Classic ASP Request.ServerVariables
>   ("AUTH_USER") or
>   Request.ServerVariables ("LOGON_USER")

It seems to work also with other browsers, not only with IE.

Thanks again to Michael Levy to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are non-IE browsers popping up a username/password dialog? I guess Firefox now supports Windows auth - http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox%20asks%20for%20user%20name%20and%20password%20on%20internal%20sites and Chrome may be supporting it soon - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19